# pytest is failed: can't find the requested URL

Tags: python, flask, pytest

I have this `Flask` app:

**myapp.py** :

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    return app

app = create_app()
session = session_factory()


def connect_db():
    engine = get_engine()
    return engine.connect()

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello everyone"
```

I want to write some pytest tests so I created two files:

**conftest.py:**

```
import pytest
from app.myapp import create_app

@pytest.fixture
def app():
    app = create_app()
    return app

@pytest.fixture
def client(app):
    return app.test_client()

@pytest.fixture
def runner(app):
    return app.test_cli_runner()
```

**test_endpoints.py**

```
import pytest
from flask import *

def test_hello(client):
    response = client.get("/")
    assert response.data == b'Hello everyone'
```

When I run pytest, I get this error:

```
>       assert response.data == b'Hello everyone'
E       assert '<!DOCTYPE HT... again.</p>\n' == 'Hello everyone'
E         + Hello everyone
E         - <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
E         - <title>404 Not Found</title>
E         - <h1>Not Found</h1>
E         - <p>The requested URL was not found on the server.  If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.</p>
```

Why `pytest` can't find the endpoint ? What can I add here to let it work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not adding any routes to the `app` you get from `create_app()` in your fixture.

If you consider your code

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    return app

app = create_app()

# ...

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello everyone"
```

, that `hello` route is only added to that global `app` instance, not the one you acquire from the fixture.

The Flask tutorial, which [covers testing](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/tests/#setup-and-fixtures), [uses blueprints to mount paths in the `create_app` function](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/tutorial/views/#id2). You might want to do that too; something like this.

```
bp = Blueprint('greetings', __name__)

@bp.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello everyone"

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.register_blueprint(bp)
    return app
```

Comment: So, in fact i'm not going to call the application endpoints directly, but I'll need to create "fake" ones and test them ?

Comment: No no. You'll just have to use blueprints for route mapping so you can reuse them between your production app and the testing instances.